# Changing Guice bindings at runtime

Tags: java, architecture, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, guice

I would like to be able to change the Guice injections at runtime to support multiple injections based on user input. This is what I would like to achieve:

```
public interface IDao {
    public int someMethod();
}

public class DaoEarth implements IDao {
    @Override
    public int someMethod(){ ... }
}

public class DaoMars implements IDao {
    @Override
    public int someMethod(){ ... }
}

public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private IDao myDao;

    public int myMethod(String domain) {
        //If Domain == Earth, myDao should be of the type DaoEarth

        //If Domain == DaoMars, myDao should be of the type DaoMars
    }
}
```

I was thinking of writing my own Provider, but I don't know how to use that provider to change my bindings at runtime. Any input is welcome and appreciated :)!

**Update**
Here's what I currently came up with, it's not as pretty as I'd like, so I'm still looking for feedback

```
public class DomainProvider {
    @Inject @Earth
    private IDaoProvider earthDaoProvider;

    @Inject @Mars
    private IDaoProvider marsDaoProvider;

    public IDaoProvider get(Domain domain){
        switch (domain){
            case EARTH:
                return earthDaoProvider;
            case MARS:
                return marsDaoProvider;
        }
    }

    public IDaoProvider get(String domain){
        Domain parsedDomain = Domain.valueOf(domain.toUpperCase());
        return get(parsedDomain);
    }
}

//MarsDaoProvider would be equivalent
public class EarthDaoProvider implements IDaoProvider {
    @Inject @Earth
    private IDao earthDao;

    public IDao getDao() {
        return earthDao;
    }
}

// This means that in "MyClass", I can do:
public class MyClass {
    @Inject
    private DomainProvider domainProvider;

    public int myMethod(String domain) {
        IDaoProvider daoProvider = domainProvider.get(domain);
        IDao dao = daoProvider.getDao();

        //Now "dao" will be of the correct type based on the domain
    }
}

//Of course elsewhere I have the bindings set like
bind(IDao.class).annotatedWith(Earth.class).to(EarthDao.class);
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how assisted injection would help me. I get that assisted injection allows you to combine injected parameters with provided parameters, but I'm not exactly sure how that would work out for my situation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your version is almost perfect as it is: You're going to need to inject some kind of object that returns one or the other based on code you write, and don't need assisted injection or anything like that. That said, you can skip some of the boilerplate:

```
public class DomainProvider {
    // Just inject Providers directly without binding them explicitly.
    @Inject @Earth Provider<IDao> earthDaoProvider;
    @Inject @Mars Provider<IDao> marsDaoProvider;

    public Provider<IDao> get(Domain domain){
        switch (domain){
            case EARTH:
                return earthDaoProvider;
            case MARS:
                return marsDaoProvider;
        }
    }

    public Provider<IDao> get(String domain){
        Domain parsedDomain = Domain.valueOf(domain.toUpperCase());
        return get(parsedDomain);
    }
}
```

Your MyClass in that case would be exactly identical. Here, `Provider` is either the one-method generic interface [com.google.inject.Provider](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html), or the equivalent  builtin [javax.inject.Provider](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html) that it extends. Read more about Guice Providers on [the relevant Guice wiki topic](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProviderBindings).

```
bind(IDao.class).annotatedWith(Earth.class).to(EarthDao.class);
// You can now inject "@Earth IDao" and also "@Earth Provider<IDao>".
```

Basically, if you bind a key `Foo` (to a class, provider, `@Provides` method, or instance), you [automatically get to inject either a `Foo` or `Provider<Foo>`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html) with no additional work. Providers are also a great way to ensure that you get a new instance with every call to `get`, if that's what you want; with your original, you'll always get the same instance of EarthDao or MarsDao for any given DomainProvider you inject. (If you have a scoped binding like @Singleton, Guice will respect that too; Provider just lets Guice get involved, rather than reusing a plain old Java reference.)

This means you can skip your custom EarthDaoProvider and MarsDaoProvider, unless you really need to perform any external initialization on them—at which point you'd probably be better off calling `bind(EarthDao.class).toProvider(EarthDaoProvider.class)` so the preparation also happens when injecting EarthDao directly. You could also just have DomainProvider return an IDao instance directly by calling `get` on the appropriate Provider, and be assured that it'll be a new instance every time.

Comment: That's an excellent answer, bonus points for the explanation/links :)

Comment: "Providers are also a great way to ensure that you get a new instance with every call to `get`" - what if I want to obtain a singleton instance instead of a new instance with every call to `get`?

Comment: @PapaSierra If you configure that in Guice, that's what you'll get; you'll want it configured that way in Guice anyway, so you can't get a different instance from another consumer. My point is that by injecting a single instance instead of a Provider, you'll always return that instance regardless of the configuration in Guice.